# Display image from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I try to display an image from mysql database into my php website But the image did not display, only the image description display. Please help why is my code did not display the image correctly. Below is the script that i use to save the image into database with blob data type.

```
*<?php
    $image = $_POST['images']['tmp_name'];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO product(image) VALUES('$image')");
    if($sql){
    echo "Product Registration Successful";
    }
    else{
         echo "Product Registration Failed";
         }
?>*
```

Below is the script that i use to display the image into the website:

```
  *<?php

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");
    while ($tampil = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ?>
    <tr>

        <td class="img-thumbnail"><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $tampil['image'] ).'"/>'; ?></td>
</tr>
 <?php  
}
?>*
```

Comment: you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: may i know how to avoid that...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: `$_POST['images']['tmp_name']` that'll be a file => `$_FILES`. Plus, you should post your HTML form. We also don't know which API you're using to connect with.

Comment: Bootstrap :     <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="?page=form_save" method="POST" enctype"multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">IMAGE</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" value="upload">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

Comment: use error reporting; the syntax error is obvious. and please don't drop code in comments, do it in your question

Answer (score 3):

You are not saving the image content to the database in your PHP, you are only saving the temporary name.

You can solve this using this code:

```
<?php
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);
$image = base64_encode($image);

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO product(image) VALUES('".$image."')");
if ($sql) {
    echo "Product Registration Successful";
} else {
    echo "Product Registration Failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: Try the updated code.

Comment: Surely they're not even saving the tmp_name because `$_POST['images'] != $_FILES['images']`

Comment: @Popnoodles Good catch, I just assumed he was using files... maybe this is totally something different.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution with:  `move_uploaded_file()`

`$image['name']['tmp_name']` is a temporary location, to store things that are deleted after a while, to actually, store the image you have to use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to another folder. This should be done after validating the image.

#### Solution for: `Base64_incode()`

IF you want to only use the base64 value, the you have to store the image information as such in the database, in this case you don't need to move the file

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($file);
ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$contents =  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Now, store `$contents` in your database.

Comment: it's still the same. I have add one field in my database with "contents"